# 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jetify - Not found

Tags: react-native

404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jetify - Not found

getting this error while npm install

React-native 0.59.5

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to https://registry.npmjs.org/jetify in your browser it returns an {"error":"Not found"}, you can see that when you navigate to https://registry.npmjs.org/jetifier you get a json object back.

So in order to solve your error you could do the following:

1. In your project/root folder in package.json change https://registry.npmjs.org/jetify to https://registry.npmjs.org/jetifier.
2. Run NPM install (or yarn)

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

404 simply means the page is not found. Make sure the url is correct.